# Ascii Tables isn't returning what it's supposed to

Tags: node.js, discord.js, ascii

```
(await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Commands/*/*.js`)).map(async (file) => {
        const command = require(file);

        if(!command.name)
        return Table.addRow(file.split("/")[7], "FAILED", "Missing a name.")

        if(!command.description)
        return Table.addRow(command.name, "FAILED", "Missing a description.")

        if(command.permission) {
            if(Perms.includes(command.permission))
            command.defaultPermission = false;
            else 
            return Table.addRow(command.name, "FAILED", "Permission is invalid.")
        }

        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        CommandsArray.push(command);

        await Table.addRow(command.name, "SUCCESFUL");

    });
```

This is returning

```
.
||
|
'
```

Basically, I want to log a command handler, but it won't work and it won't load my
commands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a variable like this:

```
const dir = process.cwd().replace(/\\/g, '/');
```

After that you need to change the line from:

```
(await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Commands/*/*.js`)).map(async (file) => {
```

to:

```
(await PG(`${dir}/Commands/*/*.js`)).map(async (file) => {
```